# Table Flexbox Problem Filling whole Width

Tags: html, css, html-table, shopify

I have a small problem with my table. I am creating a webshop with shopify and there you can write your own html code for your table.

Basically the problem is, that the table doesn't fill out the entire site. It does on mobile version because I used padding and thats necessary beause otherwise there the table shrinks to much. I just need everything staying the same but the table should fill out the whole space of the site when there is more. I tried this using flex grow 1 but it didn't work.

What it look's like if i set width to 100% and without flexbox:

[desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7h8m.png)
[mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjuBv.jpg)

What it looks like with flexbox:

[mobile flexbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmdsC.jpg)
[desktop flexbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvdCn.png)

I need another way to adjust the table object to full width without grow but it should have a minimum width because otherwise on mobile version the table looks shitty. Is there a way to grow the table lagerger when the space is given even with a set minimum padding so the table cant shrink under that on mobile.

Here is the code of my table:

```html
<style type="text/css">
  <!-- table.sizingchart {
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
  }
  
  table.sizingchart td,
  table.sizingchart tr {
    padding: 5px 15px;
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
  
  table.sizingchart tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #EEEEEE;
  }
  
  -->
</style>

<table class="sizingchart">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Length (mm)</strong></td>
      <td>44</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>49</td>
      <td>52</td>
      <td>55</td>
      <td>57</td>
      <td>60</td>
      <td>62</td>
      <td>65</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>70</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>US Size</strong></td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>UK &amp; AUS Size</strong></td>
      <td>F</td>
      <td>H</td>
      <td>J</td>
      <td>L</td>
      <td>N</td>
      <td>P</td>
      <td>R</td>
      <td>T</td>
      <td>V</td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td>Z1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>EUR Size</strong></td>
      <td>44</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>49</td>
      <td>52</td>
      <td>55</td>
      <td>57</td>
      <td>60</td>
      <td>62</td>
      <td>65</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>70</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>East Asia Size</strong></td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>16</td>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>27</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks already for the help and best regards.

Noah

Comment: i don't understand, which table is not full width?

Comment: `<style type="text/css"><!--`  you commented out the styles?

Comment: `flex-grow: 1` wont help you because `<tr>` and `<td>` are not direct children of the flex-container. `tbody` is.

Comment: I don't see `width: 100%` for that table anywhere in the code you provided above?

Answer (score 1):

`display: flex` will not help you here. Also `flex-grow: 1` for `<tr>` and `<td>` won't help you as they are not direct children to the `.sizingchart` class as `<tbody>` is.

Easiest solution is to remove flexbox and simply add: `.sizingchart { width: 100%; }`

```css
.sizingchart {
  text-align: center;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 100%; 
}

table.sizingchart td,
table.sizingchart tr {
  padding: 5px 15px;
}

table.sizingchart tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #EEEEEE;
}
```

```html
<table class="sizingchart">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Length (mm)</strong></td>
      <td>44</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>49</td>
      <td>52</td>
      <td>55</td>
      <td>57</td>
      <td>60</td>
      <td>62</td>
      <td>65</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>70</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>US Size</strong></td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>UK &amp; AUS Size</strong></td>
      <td>F</td>
      <td>H</td>
      <td>J</td>
      <td>L</td>
      <td>N</td>
      <td>P</td>
      <td>R</td>
      <td>T</td>
      <td>V</td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td>Z1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>EUR Size</strong></td>
      <td>44</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>49</td>
      <td>52</td>
      <td>55</td>
      <td>57</td>
      <td>60</td>
      <td>62</td>
      <td>65</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>70</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>East Asia Size</strong></td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>16</td>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>27</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I added some images what it looks like with your advice and what it looked like before. When i do it like you told me the table columns start overlapping ond the mobile and desktop version.

Answer (score 0):

Just erase `display:flex` (which BTW also cancels all the typical table behaviour *and*  its semantic meaning) and add `width: 100%` to the table.

And I would also reduce the side padding of the cells so they can get narrower on smaller screens.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
table.sizingchart {
  text-align: center;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

table.sizingchart td,
table.sizingchart tr {
  padding: 5px 5px;
}

table.sizingchart tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #EEEEEE;
}
```

```html
<table class="sizingchart">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Length (mm)</strong></td>
      <td>44</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>49</td>
      <td>52</td>
      <td>55</td>
      <td>57</td>
      <td>60</td>
      <td>62</td>
      <td>65</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>70</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>US Size</strong></td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>UK &amp; AUS Size</strong></td>
      <td>F</td>
      <td>H</td>
      <td>J</td>
      <td>L</td>
      <td>N</td>
      <td>P</td>
      <td>R</td>
      <td>T</td>
      <td>V</td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td>Z1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>EUR Size</strong></td>
      <td>44</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>49</td>
      <td>52</td>
      <td>55</td>
      <td>57</td>
      <td>60</td>
      <td>62</td>
      <td>65</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>70</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>East Asia Size</strong></td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>16</td>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>27</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: please check the images i added when i use your code

Comment: I don't know what you mean - you already had those images there before, didn't you? Did you reduce the side padding for the cells as I suggested? On narrow screens the table *must*  become wider than the screen since otherwise the contents won't fit in it. And concerning the desktop layout: If you really used `display: table` there, it seems you have added `table-layout: fixed;` which would explain that the first column doesn't adjust its width to its contents. If yes, erase that.

Answer (score -1):

Using the flexbox table, this is a cross-browser version. The `max-width: 550px;` of the table will set the width of the table. You may use pixels or a percentage for the max-width of each `<td>` column.

```css
.sizingchart,
.sizingchart tr {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 550px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align: center;
}
.sizingchart {
    overflow-x: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
.sizingchart tbody,
.sizingchart td {
  display: block;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.sizingchart td {
  max-width: 6%;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: inherit;
  text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
}
.sizingchart td:first-child {
  max-width: 140px;
}
.sizingchart tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<table class="sizingchart">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Length (mm)</strong></td>
      <td>44</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>49</td>
      <td>52</td>
      <td>55</td>
      <td>57</td>
      <td>60</td>
      <td>62</td>
      <td>65</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>70</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>US Size</strong></td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>UK &amp; AUS Size</strong></td>
      <td>F</td>
      <td>H</td>
      <td>J</td>
      <td>L</td>
      <td>N</td>
      <td>P</td>
      <td>R</td>
      <td>T</td>
      <td>V</td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td>Z1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>EUR Size</strong></td>
      <td>44</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>49</td>
      <td>52</td>
      <td>55</td>
      <td>57</td>
      <td>60</td>
      <td>62</td>
      <td>65</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>70</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>East Asia Size</strong></td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>16</td>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>25</td>
      <td>27</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: your snippet clearly shows that your solution does not work. Also it has no influence if you set a `flex`-property on tbody and td while you declare both as `block` in the same instance.

Comment: I do not underestand your comment because table and tr have a `display:flex` and tbody and td have a `display:block`. The block items (tbody and td) are the children of a flexbox (table and tr) so this is no problem at all. It will work cross-browser.